# React - change n dimension array object value

Tags: reactjs

I would like to change object's value in specific index of n-dimension array. main problem is that this array can have dynamic dimension. I tried with below code, but cannot change state value.

```
depth = [0, 4, 2];
treeData = [
  [ 
    [ {}, {}, ], 
    [ {}, {},  {}, {}, ], 
    [ {}, {},  {}, {},  {}, {}, ],  
    [ {}, {}, ],  
    [ {}, {}, {CHAGNE HERE}, {}]  
  ],
  [ [ {},.. ], [ {},.. ], [ {},.. ], [ {},.. ] ],
  [ [ {},.. ], [ {},.. ], [ {},.. ] ],
  ....
];


  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useRecoilState(treeDataStats)
  ...

  const clickItem = (event, item, depth) => {
    // depth refer array indexes of target object that I would like to change
    // depth value could be like [0, 4, 2] or [3, 4] 

    if (some condition) {
        const tree = [...treeData];

        var targetItem = tree;
        depth.forEach( (index) => {                         // find target object
           targetItem = targetItem[index];
        })
        targetItem = {...targetItem, key : "cliked-item"}   // targetItem is changed
        setTreeData(tree);                                  // but not tree.
    }
  }
```

Comment: How does `var targetItem = tree` find the target object?

Comment: @SinanYaman wrong comment. sorry :)

Comment: Can you install lodash and try `import _ from 'lodash'` at the top and replace `const tree = [...treeData];` with `const tree = _.cloneDeep(treeData)`

Comment: not works with deep copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, maybe a semplicistic solution but, I mean, how much is deep this `depth`?

```
 const clickItem = (event, item, depth) => {
    // depth refer array indexes of target object that I would like to change
    // depth value could be like [0, 4, 2] or [3, 4] 

    if (some condition) {
        const tree = [...treeData];

        if (depth.length === 2) {
           tree[depth[0]][depth[1]] = {...tree[depth[0]][depth[1]], key : "cliked-item"}
        }
        else if (depth.length === 3) {
           tree[depth[0]][depth[1]][depth[2]] = {...tree[depth[0]][depth[1]][depth[2]], key : "cliked-item"}
        }
        setTreeData(tree); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: cannot be confirmed.  that's my problem. :(

Comment: @DK2 the problem in your alghoritm is that when you `targetItem = targetItem[index];` in `forEach` you lost the reference to `tree` and the result is that `tree` will be not modified. But are you sure that if you manage a `depth` deep of 5 is not sufficient? 5-dimendion array is already a Penteract....

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const [treeData, setTreeData] = useRecoilState(treeDataStats)
  ...

  const clickItem = (event, item, depth) => {
    // depth refer array indexes of target object that I would like to change
    // depth value could be like [0, 4, 2] or [3, 4] 

    if (some condition) {
        let tree = [...treeData];

        // var targetItem = [...treeData];                              // find target object
        depth.map( (dep, index) => {
           let targetItem = tree[dep];
           targetItem = {...targetItem, key : "cliked-item"}
           tree[index] = targetItem;
        })
        // targetItem = {...targetItem, key : "cliked-item"}   // targetItem is changed
        setTreeData(tree);                                  // but not tree.
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would like to find 1 dim index : 0, 2 dim index : 4, 3 dim index : 2 object, NOT first depth 0, 4, 2 index object.

Comment: The depth need to be mapped, you can change the forEach to .map depth.forEach = depth.map and got it

Comment: and the tree[index] => tree[dep], i forget , sorry

Comment: You might miss understand my question. I want to change a object ( position[0][4][2]), not tree object( obj[0], obj[4], obj[2])

Comment: Yes I haven't see the example data and I am trying localy